# Node.jsのSyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: node.js

Macのターミナル上でNode.jsを動かそうとすると、SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected tokenとなってしまいます。動かそうと思っているのは以下のjsファイルです。

```
var sys = require('sys');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(
    function (request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.write('Hello World!!');
        response.end();
    }
).listen(3000);
sys.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

エラーは次のように返ってきます。

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg932\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf200
                                                               ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

何が原因かわからず困っています。解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSファイルの作り方が間違っており、RTFフォーマットで作成されているように思われます。
Macに標準の「テキストエディット」を使用して作成した場合は、デフォルトだとリッチテキストとなりますので、「標準テキスト」モードに変更してから保存する必要があります。

本格的にJSファイルを作成する場合は、プログラミング用のテキストエディタをインストールして使用することをおすすめします。